# How do I make Angular's orderBy update when new models are added?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I just started learning Angular and would have thought this is trivial, but I can't make sense of it..

I have a list of `expenses`, ordered by the `date` property:

```
<div class="expense" ng-repeat="exp in expenses | orderBy:'date'">
    <div class="c date">{{ exp.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</div>
    <div class="c amount">{{ exp.amount | currency:'£' }}</div>
    <div class="c category">{{ exp.category }}</div>
    <div class="c note">{{ exp.note }}</div>
</div>
```

I am initialising some `expenses` in the controller:

```
$scope.expenses = ({date: '01/05/2013', amount: 137, category: 'Groceries', note: ""},
      {date: '01/03/2011', amount: 100, category: 'Groceries', note: ""},
      {date: '05/05/2013', amount: 10, category: 'Entertainment', note: ""});
```

These are all displayed in the correct order at first (2011, 2013, 2013). I can then successfully add an `expense` to this list:

```
 $scope.add_exp = function() {
    $scope.expenses
    .push({date: $scope.date, amount: $scope.amount, category: $scope.category, note: $scope.note});

    // Reset fields
    $scope.date = '';
    $scope.amount = '';
    $scope.category = '';
    $scope.note = '';
  };
```

Here's the catch -- the newly added expenses are in fact ordered, but the ones present at initialisation are not taken into account.

For example, I add an item with the year 2014 into my `expenses`. The new order will be 2011, 2013, 2013, 2014. I then add an item with the year 2007, expecting it to be the first in the list. Instead, the new order is 2011, 2013, 2013, 2007, 2014 (it gets injected *after* the original `expense`s).

I've tried manually filtering `expenses` at the end of the `add_expense` function, which didn't make a difference, and using `$scope.$apply()`, which gives me an error ($apply already in progress).

Comment: Can you make a fiddle which reproduces the problem, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding date like  date:'01/05/2013' 
 use `date: new Date('01/05/2013')` and it will work perfectly

Comment: Thanks---I initialised a Date object in both the initial `expenses` array as well as when pushing new objects and it worked!

Comment: by doing as Elise said, do this `new Date()` on both the initial scope and the pushed one made it work for me. Phew heavy 6 hours of solving this, and I wasn't even on the correct line when trying out things.